# How to use cellIdentityNr & cellSignalNr show some information in 5G?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have used some commands to display some parameters in 3G and 4G environment.I successfully used these commands to get the desired parameters.But it does not work in 5G (Nr) environment, what is the problem?My api is already update to 29.

```
private fun getCellInfo(cellInfo:CellInfo): HashMap<Any? ,String?> {
    var netclass = getNetworkClass()
    Log.d("MyActivity",netclass)
    var map = hashMapOf<Any?, String?>()
    if (cellInfo is CellInfoGsm) {
        val cellIdentityGsm = cellInfo.cellIdentity
        val cellSignalGsm = cellInfo.cellSignalStrength
        map["cell_identity"]=cellIdentityGsm.cid.toString()
        map["MCC"]=cellIdentityGsm.mcc.toString()
        map["MNC"]=cellIdentityGsm.mnc.toString()
        map["LAC"]=cellIdentityGsm.lac.toString()
        map["RSSI"]=cellSignalGsm.dbm.toString()
        map["RxLev"]=cellSignalGsm.asuLevel.toString()
        map["Level_of_strength"]=cellSignalGsm.level.toString()
        map["type"]="2"
    } else if (cellInfo is CellInfoLte) {
        val cellIdentityLte = cellInfo.cellIdentity
        val cellSignalStrengthLte = cellInfo.cellSignalStrength
        map["cell_identity"] = cellIdentityLte.ci.toString()
        map["MCC"] = cellIdentityLte.mcc.toString()
        map["MNC"] = cellIdentityLte.mnc.toString()
        map["TAC"] = cellIdentityLte.tac.toString()
        map["RSRP"] = cellSignalStrengthLte.rsrp.toString()
        map["RSRQ"] = cellSignalStrengthLte.rsrq.toString()
        map["Level_of_strength"] = cellSignalStrengthLte.level.toString()
        map["type"] = "4"
    } else if (cellInfo is CellInfoWcdma) {
        val cellIdentityWcdma = cellInfo.cellIdentity
        val cellSignalWcdma = cellInfo.cellSignalStrength
        map["cell_identity"]=cellIdentityWcdma.cid.toString()
        map["MCC"]=cellIdentityWcdma.mcc.toString()
        map["MNC"]=cellIdentityWcdma.mnc.toString()
        map["LAC"]=cellIdentityWcdma.lac.toString()
        map["RSCP"]=cellSignalWcdma.dbm.toString()
        map["Level_of_strength"]=cellSignalWcdma.level.toString()
        map["type"]="3"
    }else if (cellInfo is CellInfoNr){
        val  cellIdentityNr = cellInfo.cellIdentity
        val cellSignalStrengthNr = cellInfo.cellSignalStrength
        map["cell_identity"]=cellIdentityNr.Nci.toString() //wrong here
        map["RSRP"]=cellSignalStrengthNr.asuLevel.toString()
    }
    map["net_type"]=netclass
    map["plmn"] = tm.getNetworkOperator().toString()
    return map
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CXwo.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of 5G networks, SA and NSA, the above class, returns the values for SA which is not widely implemented. the NSA use LTE for signalling and 5G for Data. so If you are using Public Operator 5G service, it may be NSA, and you should somehow extract info from allCellInfo.

Amin.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).